# Vote on a Snapshot with a deployed Safe using the Safe SDK?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, snapshot

I'm wondering how the code might look/if it's possible to use the Safe Core SDK to deploy a safe, then vote on a Snapshot proposal? Suppose I have a safe, successfully created with:

```
const safe = await safeFactory.deploySafe({
  { owners, threshold },
  saltNonce,
  callback: (hash) =>
    console.log(`Tx hash: ${hash}`),
});
```

And I can create the snapshot client:

```
const client = new snapshot.Client712('https://testnet.hub.snapshot.org');
```

How might I modify this example (from the snapshot docs), to vote with the safe I've created?

```
const web3 = new Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const [account] = await web3.listAccounts();

const receipt = await client.vote(web3, account, {
  space: 'yam.eth',
  proposal: '0x21ea31e896ec5b5a49a3653e51e787ee834aaf953263144ab936ed756f36609f',
  type: 'single-choice',
  choice: 1,
  reason: 'Choice 1 make lot of sense',
  app: 'my-app'
});
```

I assume the `account` would be the address of the deployed safe, and in my case I am not creating a provider from `window.ethereum`, rather `new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider` using an Alchemy RPC endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely right, `account` would be in this case the address of your newly deployed safe.

If you have access to the `window` object with an web3 provider like MetaMask, you might use `new Web3Provider(window.ethereum)`. If not, you should be able to use `ethers` with an RPC endpoint as you suggested.

Hope it helps,
Louis